# Magento getConfigurableAttributesAsArray causes fatal error

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to write a script that creates configurable products. Ive been using this as a guide: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/

When I get to this line:

```
$configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
```

The script crashes and kicks out this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/buyfrom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 283
```

Following [a comment on this page](http://www.sharpdotinc.com/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/), I changed that line to the following:

```
$possibleAttributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

But I am still getting this error. Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that attribute set (eg. default) which you are choosing is having at least one configurable attribute (example: 'color' or 'size').

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).